# can you help me with this error fhimagefactory?

Tags: android, titanium

can you help me with this problem?

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user1/Documents/Apps/modules/android/fh.imagefactory/android/fhimagefactory.jar'

I tried updating the android modules but it didn't work

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some more info like Ti SDK version, Ti CLI version and which module you are using (version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use an old version of the module please have a look at this fork
https://github.com/m1ga/fh.imagefactory
and try the ZIP in https://github.com/m1ga/fh.imagefactory/tree/master/android/dist

Make sure you use an update to date Titanium SDK version, Ti CLI version and that your node version is correct.

As a reference: Ti SDK 12.1.1.GA (everything from 11.x should be fine), Ti CLI 6.1.1 (run `sudo npm i -g titanium` to update), Node 16.

Comment: I was able to resolve the error for fh.imagefactory but I get the same error with ti.goosh. Could you help me?

Comment: it would help if you say how you solved the error :) Did you update the module or did you do something else? ti.goosh is a deprecated module since GCM is gone for years now. And there is https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging for FCM

Comment: Of course I was able to solve the problem thanks to the fh.imagefactory module that you sent me.

Comment: ok, then the solution is the new FCM module in this case too